# Angle Coefficient Generator for Landsat 4-5-7 from USGS does not work

Tags: landsat

I'm currently trying to use the function proposed here :
https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/solar-illumination-and-sensor-viewing-angle-coefficient-files?qt-science_support_page_related_con=1#qt-science_support_page_related_con
by the USGS.
The main purpose is to produce pixel-based sun-surface-sensor geometry information, such as Viewing Zenith Angle (VZA) or Solar Zenith Angle (SZA).

To do it, it is explain that we have to download a function, one for Landsat 4 to 7 and one for Landsat 8. Both function need to be used through bash script.

The input for the function is simply the *_ANG.txt metadata file downloaded from earth explorer and the output are pixel-based VZA and SZA for each band.

It works perfectly for landsat 8 (l8_angles function) but the function for other landsat (landsat_angles) return this error :

```
angle coefficient filename is /PATH/LT05_L1TP_195029_19960724_20180215_01_T1/LT05_L1TP_195029_19960724_20180215_01_T1_ANG.txt.
Unable to open the output file.  Messages will be written to the terminal

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parsing File:  /PATH/LT05_L1TP_195029_19960724_20180215_01_T1/LT05_L1TP_195029_19960724_20180215_01_T1_ANG.txt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------
End of Parsing File:  /PATH/LT05_L1TP_195029_19960724_20180215_01_T1/LT05_L1TP_195029_19960724_20180215_01_T1_ANG.txt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

2019 134 18:27:52  Angle Gen   2159      gxx_angle_gen_read_ang.c      1062    Unable to open the output file.  Messages will be written to the terminal
: check out /usr/tmp/ODLEr15578512729045452159.dat
2019 134 18:27:52  Angle Gen   2159      landsat_angles.c            82    Error reading the angle coefficient file.
```

The code calling the function is :

```
./landsat_angles/landsat_angles $pathtoAng
```

with $pathtoAng corresponding to the Path ending with _ANG.txt

Can't find anything on the internet.
Can't propose data to test for the bug.

Answer (score 1):

As i remember, the function tries to open a temporary file in /usr/tmp. And it fails: "Unable to open the output file". Then returns error code to main func, that prints to stderr, that something wrong with reading the ANG file. 
So make sure you have write permissions to the /usr/tmp.